# Electron: starting terminal in main window

Tags: node.js, shell, terminal, electron, embed

I'm using something like

child_process.exec('start cmd.exe /K bash -c "some commands..."')

to start a terminal. Everything works fine. Of course the terminal opens as a separate window. Is there a way to embed this terminal in the main app window?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to achieve this. One would be using something like [xterm](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/). Microsoft Visual Studio Code uses it I believe.

From their description:

> Xterm.js is a terminal front-end component written in JavaScript that
>   works in the browser.
>
> It enables applications to provide fully featured terminals to their
>   users and create great development experiences.